# How to do a select statement query with comma separator?

Tags: range, axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, x++

I need to do a simple query, *Select Statement*

I want to search in Table all record with value "ValueA, ValueB".

If I use this code, not work well:

```
String255 valueToFilter;
valueToFilter = 'ValueA, ValueB';

select count (RecId) from MyTable
                    where MyTable.Field like valueToFilter ;
```

But not working, I need to keep all record with value "ValueA" or "ValueB", if in the file there is value like : "ValueA, ValueC" I want to get too.

I don't know the number of values (*valueToFilter*).

Thanks!

Comment: instead of `like` use `in`

Comment: Thanks @Anat, but if I use ON I get a syntax error, I'm writing this JOB on x++ , in AOT.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my point of view the easiest way to accomplish this is to split your filter string:

```
String255 valueToFilterA = 'ValueA';
String255 valueToFilterB = 'ValueB';
;

select count (RecId) from MyTable
    where MyTable.Field like valueToFilterA 
       || MyTable.Field like valueToFilterB;
```

If you don't know the number of values you should use `query` object to add ranges dynamically:

```
Query                   query = new Query();
QueryRun                queryRun;
QueryBuildDataSource    qbds;
QueryBuildRange         queryRange;
container               conValues;
;

qbds = query.addDataSource(tableNum(MyTable));

for (i = 1; i <= conlen(conValues); i++)
{
    queryRange = qbds.addRange(fieldNum(MyTable, Field));   
    queryRange.value(SysQuery::valueLike(conPeek(conValues, i)));
} 

queryRun = new QueryRun(query);    
info(strFmt("Records count %1", SysQuery::countTotal(queryRun)));
```

Comment: Hi @Aliaksandr Maksimau thanks for your answer. I have a problmem is as I don't know the number of values. Sometime I have to find only "ValueA" and sometime I have to find "ValueA, ValueB, ValueN" etc... I appreace your time.

Comment: If you don't know the number of values you should use `query` object to accomplish this task. There are two method in `SysQuery` class `ValueLike`, `ValueLikeAfter` that will be of your use.

Comment: If your values do not contain magic characters like * or ?, you can just add the filter range directly in the query: `queryRange.value(valueToFilter)`

Comment: Thanks all for yours time. Work well.